# How do I center an image with a width less than 100%?

Tags: html, css

When I have display as 100%, everything displays fine, but I'd like to have the image a little smaller so I've set the width as 30% for now - the issue with this is that the image stops centering once I do that (would anybody know why that's the case?).

If I remove display block, it centers, but then sits on the same line as the button - however if I then add in display:block to the button, the left/right padding stretches across the width of the container.

Here's the codepen where I've saved my project: https://codepen.io/vivl/pen/GRWYeaw - but here's the code I'm having trouble with:

```
.image {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 30%;
    border-top: 1px solid #cee5d0;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: via àuto horizontal margin : `margin:0 auto  25px;`

Comment: ```margin-left: auto; ``` and ```margin-right: auto;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center an image, set left and right margin to auto and make it into a block element. For example:

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Here is the link that I found this answer in -> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_center.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can set auto margins to buttons and icons and make buttons display: block; and width: fit-content:

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* CSS RESET */

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #9fe6a0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.pricing {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1900px;
    padding: 50px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; */
}

/* .button:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
} */

.pricing-plan {
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 3em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cee5d0;
}

.pricing-features-item {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #4aa96c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cee5d0;
}

.pricing-plan-cost {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 3em;
    display: block;
}

.button {
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #2f5d62;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
}

.image {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 30%;
    border-top: 1px solid #cee5d0;
    /* Removed display: block; */
}

.image:nth-of-type(1) {
    border-top: none;
}

/* Styles added by me */
image {
  margin: auto;
}
.button {
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
    <title>Pricing Meal Plan</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="pricing table plan">

        <img class="image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/2366/2366518.png">
        <h2 class="pricing-plan">Individual</h2>
        <ul class="pricing-plan-features">
            <li class="pricing-features-item">3 portions/day</li>
            <li class="pricing-features-item">Includes Vegetarian, Meat-lovers & Mixed options</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="pricing-plan-cost">$24</span>
        <a href="#/" class="button">Order Now</a>


        <img class="image" src=https://img-premium.flaticon.com/png/512/2082/2082045.png?token=exp=1623515154~hmac=5fe8a85c5f61e9bc650f5c8cae14487f>
        <h2 class="pricing-plan">Two Share</h2>
        <ul class="pricing-plan-features">
            <li class="pricing-features-item">6 portions a day</li>
            <li class="pricing-features-item">Enough two share!</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="pricing-plan-cost">$40</span>
        <a href=#/ class="button">Order Now</a>


        <img class="image" src=https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/2620/2620464.png>
        <h2 class="pricing-plan">Family Plan</h2>
        <ul class="pricing-plan-features">
            <li class="pricing-features-item">14 portions a day</li>
            <li class="pricing-features-item">Suitable for big families with even bigger appetites</li>
        </ul>
        <span class="pricing-plan-cost">$120</span>
        <a href="#/" class="button">Order Now</a>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first wrap the image with a div

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="link" class="img-class_name">
</div>
```

Now style the outer div like this

```
.img-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the margin to place in center irrespective of the image size. Here use this code :

```
.image {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    width: 30%;
    border-top: 1px solid #cee5d0;
    display: block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```